# Vertical alignment of multiple consecutive tables

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, chapters

The aim is to align multiple (often quite large) consecutive captioned tables within respective chapters, for example: chap 1, table 1.1, table 1.2, table 1.3 --- chap 2, table 2.1, table 2.2...

There is no text between the tables. The tables are in the usual table format (see the MWE) which I would like to keep, if possible.

Here are two pictures from the following MWE. The first shows a chapter, some random text, and the normal distance I wanted to achieve after each new chapter in the document labelled as 'target distance'.

[image: target distance]

The second picture shows that the distance between chapters and tables is bigger than the normal one:

[image]

Here is the MWE:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline, smallheadings,]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[labelfont={small,bf}, textfont=small, labelsep=colon,singlelinecheck=false,format=plain, parindent=1em]{caption}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace{-1.8\baselineskip}}
\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
\chapter{B}
Some text to show the target distance from a chapter headline

\chapter{A}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Description}
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\toprule
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE  \\
ABCDE &
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE  \\
ABCDE & 
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE  \\
ABCDE &
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE  \\
ABCDE & 
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE  \\
ABCDE &
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE  \\
ABCDE & 
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE  \\
ABCDE &
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE  \\
ABCDE & 
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Description}
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\toprule
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE  \\
ABCDE &
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE  \\
ABCDE & 
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE  \\
ABCDE &
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE  \\
ABCDE & 
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE  \\
ABCDE &
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE  \\
ABCDE & 
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Description}
{\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{lccccc}
\toprule
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE & ABCDE \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Best regards, Tom.

Comment: Does [KOMA-script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) provide `\raggedbottom`? That may remove what currently seems like stretching of the baselines to accommodate for the underfilled pages...

Comment: @Werner I don't know but I have just tried to add the command to the preamble of the MWE and it doesn't have any effect. So it seems not to work.

Comment: Adding \vfill after the table does nothing, so it's not an expansion problem.  Interestingly, \vspace*{-.5cm} is about .5cm too little and \vspace*{-1cm} is way too much.

Comment: Duh!  Screen size has nothing to do with actual size.  Putting \vspace*{-.65cm} appears about right.  Either after the \chapter or after the \table works just as well.

Comment: @JohnKormylo yep I also played around with `\captionsetup{aboveskip=length}`, but that is more of a guesswork than a real solution. But at least you seem to have found the exact value in this case, `\vspace*{-.65cm}` :)
If nothing more automated can be done here I will definitely use it. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnKormylo there is also one limitation with this approach: it works after headings, but it doesn't work on the following pages without chapters. Tables are vertically centered there. So the guess work had to be done again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@karlkoeller has solved part the problem in another thread by using the command `\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{-x pt}`. This solves the distance problem for pages which contain a headline.

In case of pages which do not contain a headline, originally floating tables (eg page 3 of the MWE) can be prevented from floating by loading the `float`-package and setting the floating parameter to `[H]`. After that the target distance can be set by using `vspace` via trial and error.

This is the solution that I am currently using. If anyone else has a better one, feel free to post it.