# Floating parameter [H] streches table vertically

Tags: floats, vertical-alignment

I am currently using `[H]` as a floating parameter for a list of tables in the appendix. The idea is to make the tables in the appendix start at the same vertical distance from the top on every page ([Vertical alignment of multiple consecutive tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151502/vertical-alignment-of-multiple-consecutive-tables)).

Now the problem is that `[H]` streches the table in that the **distance between the rows becomes larger**. Where does this come from?

Instead I wanted to use `[H]` only to eliminate the floating behaviour but at the same time keep the formatting consistent. See the following example to illustrate the problem. You can swap `[H]` for `!h` and both tables will look exactly the same, as desired, but the vertical distance from the top is ruined.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, headsepline, headings=small,]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{float}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Tables}


\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\caption{Table caption} 
\label{magic numbers}
{\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{l*{7}{c}}
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{D} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{E} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{F} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{G}  \\
A & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
B & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
C & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
D & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\
E & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
A & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
B & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
C & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
D & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\
E & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\
A & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
B & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
C & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
D & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\
E & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
A & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
B & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
C & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
D & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\
E & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\
A & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
B & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
C & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
D & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\
E & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
A & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
B & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
C & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
D & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\
E & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
A & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
B & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
C & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
D & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\
E & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\    
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}

\vspace*{18pt}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{Table caption} 
\label{magic numbers}
{\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{l*{7}{c}}
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{C} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{D} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{E} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{F} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{G}  \\
A & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
B & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
C & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
D & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\
E & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
A & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
B & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
C & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
D & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\
E & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\
A & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
B & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
C & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
D & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\
E & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
A & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
B & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
C & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
D & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\
E & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\
A & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
B & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
C & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
D & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\
E & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
A & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
B & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
C & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
D & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\
E & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
A & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
B & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
C & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\ 
D & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\
E & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42 & 54.42& 54.42& 54.42\\  
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

So in the end the aim is to align multiple tables (in the appendix) consistently, ie starting at the same point from the top. Maybe there is a way to achieve this manually? I could do this by hand for the respective tables, the solution really does not have to be automized. Also I only want to achieve this behaviour in the appendix, but not in the main document, as the floating is working fine there.

Thanks.

Comment: `H` does nothing at all with the contents of the `table`, it just turns it into a minipage rather than a float.  Your `\scriptsize` usage is incorrect, you should not have the `{}` and if you _do_ use `{}` you must always include `\par` or a blank line before the closing `}` otherwise the line spacing will be all wrong.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oh that's interesting. My tables are coming from `xtable`, I really have to investigate if this a package error then. Just for clarification, could you show me an example how it's done correctly? Just remove the brackets `{}`? Edit: I just removed the brackets, but that didn't help in my MWE.

Comment: actually that ought to be the case but I just ran  your example and I see what you mean, got to go now, will answer later if no one else has

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a question of the loading order of packages.  You need to load `setspace` after `float`; both of them interact with internal LaTeX command `\@xfloat`.

Wrong: `\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}` before `\usepackage{float}`

[image: Sample wrong output]

Right: `\usepackage{float}` before `\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}`

[image: Sample correct output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Tables}

\begin{table}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    1\\
    1\\
    1
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    1\\
    1\\
    1
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Indeed it is. That solved the problem, thanks a lot :)